# BIRT get list of required parameters in report

Tags: java, birt

Suppose I have a report that has some required parameters to set before execute.
If I execute report in a BIRT viewer, pop-up asking to enter required parameters appears.
I use BIRT API, and I don't want to deploy BIRT viewer in my app.
How can I programmatically get the list of parameters I need to set before executing the report?

Or saying another way, how can I get to know programmatically, what parameters should be set before executing?

And how to set into the report values I get from the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found following decision.
We should define a separate task:

```
IGetParameterDefinitionTask taskGetParameters = engine
                .createGetParameterDefinitionTask(design);
```

After that we can get an Iterator of parameters from this task:

```
Collection params = taskGetParameters.getParameterDefns(true);
        Iterator iter = params.iterator();
```

After that we can iterate over the parameters and get their properties. I am gettting the name of parameter and its help text which I define at the stage of report design, and where I store type and default value:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            IParameterDefnBase param = (IParameterDefnBase) iter.next();
            System.out.println(param.getName() + ": " + param.getHelpText());
        }
```

Then I form a Hashmap of parameters, key is name, value is value, and pass it to the IRunAndRenderTask:

```
HashMap<String, String> setParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
//some code for adding parameters to the hashmap is here
IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
task.setParameterValues(setParameters);
EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();
options.setOutputFormat("csv");
options.setOutputFileName("output\\myxls.csv");
task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();
task.close();
```

I omit some code to avoid a lot of text here, surely one has to close the engine and all BIRT resources to avoid memory leaks.

As you see, the main point is that we need to get parameter properties from one task and pass to another task.

I found some hints [here](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/reapi.php).